# TypeError: invalid file: ('D:/xxx.txt', ' ') when using getOpenFileName()

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5

I have a trouble with opening file using FileDialog in python 3.4 and Pyqt5.

This is part of my code:

```
def SaveFile(self):
    filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    file = open(filename, 'w')
```

When I trying to execute this and select file, i getting:

```
TypeError: invalid file: ('D:/dsgdsg.txt', '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the error message, `getOpenFileName` returns a `tuple`. If you want to get the filename (the first element of the tuple), you need to do this:

```
filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
```

or

```
filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

Comment: Happy to help :-). If this answer solves you problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.